# WAMP SERVER Use Other Port Other Than 443 for HTTPS

Tags: apache, ssl, https, wamp, wampserver

I am trying to enable a port different from 443 on WAMP Server Version 3.2.3. I tried using 8443, 4431, 444, 4433, just to name a few. When I type in `https://localhost` using one of the different ports, I get `connection refused`. If I try localhost:XXXX (other than 443), it returns a `bad gateway error (400)`.

I want to preface by saying that it was in fact working with 443, but I need it **to not** work off of Port 443 and something else instead. I've scrounged the internet and have come up with nothing. Everywhere I looked, it said simply to change the httpd-ssl.conf `Listen 443` line to `Listen XXXX` (not 443) and that it would work, but it does not. Please tell me if I am missing something.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you also change `<VirtualHost _default_:443>` or `<VirtualHost *:443>` to `<VirtualHost *:8443>`? Also change the Listen to 8443

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65962030/apache-virtual-host-on-different-ports-doesnt-work

Answer (score 0):

After changing:

```
Listen 8443
```

Also change the line like: `<VirtualHost _default_:443>` or `<VirtualHost *:443>`, to:

```
<VirtualHost *:8443>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I had that. I changed the virtualhost port as well as the domain's port to 8443. Essentially changed all of the references to 443 to 8443, but it breaks everything.

Comment: Doesn't work for me