# Apache virtual host on different ports doesn't work

Tags: apache, xampp, webserver, virtualhost, httpd.conf

I'm trying to serve different folders on my localhost. I'm using Windows OS.

I want to serve `E:/Programming/Projects` on `localhost:8080`, and `E:/htdocs` on `localhost:80`

My `httpd-vhosts.conf` file is like that:

```
Listen 8080
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot "E:/Programming/Projects"
    <Directory "E:/Programming/Projects">
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

When I attempt to navigate localhost:80, this port works well. But localhost:8080 gives this error:

```
403 - Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource.
```

I've reset my server, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer is:

```
Listen 8080

<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerName localhost:8080
    DocumentRoot "E:/Programming/Projects/"
    <Directory "E:/Programming/Projects/">
        Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Much safer to limit the require to the local network like `require ip 192.168.1`